# Why is Lumina desktop not booting?

Tags: openbsd

I am using here OpenBSD 6.1 ; I am trying to use Lumina desktop as my graphical interface in `xorg`; however while `start-lumina-desktop` boots properly from command line in text mode in a terminal while running X, it does not boot if invoked via the `.xinitrc` file.

I already have found looking at the `xenodm` scripts, I have to use `.xsession` instead of `.xinitrc`; however if the `.xsession` file is:

```
start-lumina-desktop
```

when logging from `xenodm`, you cannot enter your desktop, it dies, and you return to the login screen.

And the error it returns in the file `.xsession-errors` is:

`start-lumina-desktop:/usr/local/lib/libicuuc.so.12.0: /usr/local/lib/libicudata.so.12.0 : WARNING: symbol(icudt58_dat) size mismatch, relink your program`

I already reinstalled the package `icu4c-58.2p0` with:

```
pkg_add -r -D installed icu4c
```

and also did:

```
pkg_add -u
```

Why is not `Lumina desktop` booting?

Comment: Don't worry about that warning. You should ask in the ports@ list and CC the mail to the maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging, it is clearly inconsequential whether `icu4c` is giving a warning or not.

Both `start-lumina-desktop` and `lumina-desktop` are dying or giving an error when called from `xenodm`, and complaining X is already running when called from text console mode; when calling from a Terminal in `fvwm`, it runs without problems.

The actual problem is that `xenodm` does not have the PATH of `lumina-desktop` in the PATH. However it is not enough to reference `start-lumina-desktop` or `lumina-desktop` by the full name.

So to be able to login from `xenodm` to `lumina-desktop` the ´.xsession` file  should be:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin start-lumina-desktop
```

Once that is corrected, I am able to start an user session from `xenodm` entering the `lumina-desktop`